# Enable Button when row selected in DataGrid using Expression Blend?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

As titled, I want to enable the a Button (that was disabled) when a row from DataGrid (so an object) is selected.

From what I read, WPF seems to have triggers for check when centain property change it can do centain thing?

But in Silverlight it seems I can only use GoToState instead.  I tried to make two states: Selected and UnSelected.  But the IsEnabled property for the Button it doesn't seems being record from UnSelected state to Selected state...

And another problem is the only event that fits from DataGrid is SelectionChanged, but how do I ensure that the User does selected a Row?

If I do everything in code-behide I can check SelectionChangedEvent and enable the buttons, but is there anyway to do everything above with Expression Blend?  I am trying to put everything in xaml as much as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using ordinary Element binding? For example:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" />
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=MyGrid, Converter={StaticResource MyNullToBoolConverter}}" />
```

and an example of the converter:

```
class MyNullToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? true : false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

All you have to do then is declare the converter in the static resources of either the page or the Button.

Comment: Oo, I see.  So there Expression blend doesn't supporting do such things natively? I mean like without writting converter or code?

Comment: @King, I'm not an Expression pro, I do all my XAML directly in VS (so I can't say whether Expression has that ability or not). You could probably also do this with a DataTrigger or some sort of behavior, I simply showed the quickest way to achieve what you want. One way or another you will have to use a converter or expression, as the presense or lack thereof of an object in SelectedItem needs to be equated to a boolean value.